# Gridgain: Get an object value from GridCache

Tags: gridgain

With reference to the example CachePutGetExample.java, 
https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain-advanced-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/putget/CachePutGetExample.java

Test1: With the putx part in the code, getx works fine

`for (int i = 0; i < keyCnt; i++)
  cache.putx(i, Integer.toString(i));`

Test2: With the putx part commented, getx works fine

`for (int i = 0; i < keyCnt; i++)
  cache.putx(i, Integer.toString(i));`

When I try to get the values, I'm able to retrieve them

But when I changed the GridCache to:

`final GridCache<Integer, Person> cache = g.cache(CACHE_NAME);`

and run the same tests,

Test1: with putx part in the code, getx works fine

`for (int i = 0; i < keyCnt; i++)
  cache.putx(i, person1);`

Test2: without putx part in the code, getx returns null

`for (int i = 0; i < keyCnt; i++)
  cache.putx(i, person1);`

Am I going wrong somewhere? Or is it like that in GridGain, when we use object as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code gets automatically undeployed (which means that caches get cleared) whenever you shutdown the main node. You can change this behavior in 2 ways:

1. Change configuration setting for deployment mode to `CONTINUOUS` (it is set to `SHARED` by default). In this case, the classes will not be automatically undeployed whenever the master node leaves.
2. Build examples.jar (you can do it with maven) and copy the Jar file into `libs` folder on every node. This way the classes will be locally deployed on every node and, therefore, will not be undeployed whenever any node leaves.